# How to add Transparent texture image with another texture

Tags: texturing, transparency

I am trying to mix two different materials together, I want to add one with texture, and another one with a transparent image texture.

I made the first texture called **wood.001**

than I **assign** new texture on the faces **texturee**

the issue is that the new **texturee** make the **wood.001** transparent too, I want to keep the wood texture and add a new transparent image on the top of it.

**Texture**

[image: Textures]

**Node**
[image]

**Resulet**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it all using one material. Use your Wood Texture instead of the Transparent BSDF in your node setup (you will have to run it through some shader first such as a Diffuse BSDF or another Principled BSDF). The alpha from your 916-01 image will define the mix between the two textures (no need for a Transparent Shader).

[image: Mix]

For reference, this is the checker board texture (showing the alpha) that is being overlayed over the wood:
[image: Checker]

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much~ that's helping me a lot